# Contar numero de elementos de uma lista python

Tags: python

tenho a seguinte lista:

```
lista = [ 'A','B','C','D']
```

eu quero que conte o numero de elementos ate determinado ponto, eu sei que se fizer `len(lista)` vai contar todos os elementos mas oque eu quero é por exemplo ate o C ele vai me dar o numero 3.

Comment: Um for não resolveria o seu problema?

Comment: mas tipo usei pra contar ate o C só como exemplo, eu quero fazer uma pergunta, e contar ate a letra que a pessoa responder

Comment: Mas isso da para fazer com for, vou fazer uma resposta como exemplo para você

Comment: Eu iria responder, mas o Marcos .p, fez um código melhor que o meu

Comment: @WictorChaves sua resposta é diferente e também da o resultado esperado por ele, mais de uma solução é bem vinda sempre! :D

Comment: E se houverem dados repetidos na lista? Por exemplo, `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c']`, o resultado deve ser 3 ou 5? Deve sempre considerar a primeira ocorrência?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apenas pegue o índice e some com mais  1, já que o primeiro índice é 0.

```
lista = ['A','B','C','D']
print lista.index('C') + 1;
```

> Para pegar o índice do array utilize o método "index".

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o index para encontrar a posição do elemento desejado e calcular a quantidade descontando do total de elementos, por exemplo:

```
lista = [ 'A','B','C','D']
indice = lista.index('C')
(indice + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma seria usando o for, como o Wictor propos nos comentários:

```
i = 0
lista = [ 'A','B','C','D']

for x in lista:
  i+=1
  if x == 'C':
    break;
print(i)
```

Mas usando `index()` da resposta do Wictor é mais simples e elegante.